# Inserir e Editar com CodIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

Na realidade não é bem uma dúvida mas sim se podem me indicar alguma direção a tomar sobre um assunto.

Peguei um projeto para corrigir e o desenvolvedor usou CodeIgniter, mas o projeto é bem grande e com isso temos diversos arquivos.

O grande problema é que para cada Produto, Categoria, Usuário, etc o desenvolvedor criou uma view para editar os dados (edit_user.php) e uma página para inserir um novo usuário (new_user.php), qual a diferença entre as duas:

**A única diferença é que na primeira view os campos de INPUT possui o value (`$user[0]->txtNome` e na segunda view os campos value estão em branco**

O problema disso é que se eu alterar ou inserir um campo para o usuário, tenho que alterar as duas páginas, muito trabalho.

Uma solução seria colocar um IF em todos os inputs, mas isso poderia ficar gigante, dependente da quantidade de campos do formulário.

Outra saída seria criar um objet com o nome de todos os campos e atribuir o valor igual a NULO, o que ficaria grande também.

A pergunta é:

- Existe alguma forma de no CodeIgniter criarmos isto dinamicamente, ou seja, usando um set_fields, criando um objeto vazio, etc.

Não gostaria de usar CRUD dinâmicos como GROCERY, então se alguém tiver alguma sugestão ou uma direção poderiam me dar, agradeço a ajuda de todos

Comment: posta um trecho do código da view

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, como você está usando o Codeigniter, não sei se existe uma solução eficaz propriamente nele. Talvez exista algujma biblioteca ou helper que possa te auxiliar nisso.

Mas acredito que você possa resolver esse problema simplesmente usando um `isset`, através condição ternária, para saber se vai imprimir ou não.

Se o seu formulário estiver assim:

```
<input name="nome" value="<?= $dados->nome ?>">
```

Você pode fazer simplesmente uma das opções abaixo

```
<input name="nome" value="<?= isset($dados->nome) ? $dados->nome : null ?>" >

<input name="nome" value="<?php isset($dados->nome) and print $dados->nome ?>" >
```

Penso eu que editores como Sublime Text poderiam ajudar a fazer essa alteração mais rápido.